# Compare QDateTime

Tags: python, datetime, pyqt5

```
self.start_date = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_start_date_2.date().toString()
self.time_start = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_start_time_2.time().toString()
self.end_date = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_end_date_2.date().toString()
self.end_time = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_end_time_2.time().toString()
```

I want to check if start_datetime<end_datetime.

Any advice would be useful.

I tried this:

```
date_1 = self.start_date+" "+self.time_start
date_2 = self.end_date+" "+self.end_time
date_1_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_1, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')
date_2_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_2, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')
print(date_1_time_obj<date_2_time_obj)
```

Error:

`ValueError: time data '╙άέ ╔άΊ 1 2000 00:00:00' does not match format '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S'`

The error happens because `.toString()` returns day of week and month in local format (greek characters)

Comment: to me looks like the error is related to `.toString()`, seems like the encoding of the string is incorrect.

Comment: @MrFuppes I found a solution.
Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.start_date = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_start_date_2.date().toPyDate()
self.time_start = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_start_time_2.time().toPyTime()
self.end_date = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_end_date_2.date().toPyDate()
self.end_time = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_end_time_2.time().toPyTime()
                
                
                
date_1_time_obj = datetime.datetime.combine(self.start_date, self.time_start)
date_2_time_obj = datetime.datetime.combine(self.end_date, self.end_time)
print(date_1_time_obj<date_2_time_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do just what your title says: compare objects of type `QDateTime`, that's already possible just like that.

```
date1 = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
date2 = QDateTime.currentDateTime().addMonths(1)

date1 < date2
=> True
```

And if you want to combine the date and the time first it should go about this way:

```
start_date = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_start_date_2
start_time = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_start_time_2

end_date = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_end_date_2
end_time = ui.new_scheduled_transmition_day_end_time_2

date_1 = QDateTime(start_date).addMSecs(start_time.msecsSinceStartOfDay())
date_2 = QDateTime(end_date).addMSecs(end_time.msecsSinceStartOfDay())

date1 < date2
```

See https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QDateTime.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QDateTime.__lt__ for more information.